# set colname to cell value conditionally

Tags: r, datatable, data-manipulation

I have got problem with assigning colnames to cell values under condition. 
I want to assign colname to cell value when it's equal 4. My data:

```
DT <- data.table(mtcars[1:5, -c(1:8)])
```

My desired result:

```
DT2 = data.table(am = rep(NA, 5), gear = c("gear", "gear", "gear", NA, NA), carb = c("carb", "carb", NA, NA, NA))
```

I tried with:

```
DT[, gear:= ifelse((gear==4), colnames(DT), NA )]
```

but it took all colnames. I need to use specific colname and do it for hundreds of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping through the columns, initally `set` the columns to `character` as it is `numeric`, and then look for the index where the value is 4 in each column and set the `value` with the corresponding column names

```
for(j in seq_along(DT)) {
   set(DT, i = NULL, j =j, value = as.character(DT[[j]]))
   set(DT, i = which(DT[[j]] ==4), j = j, value = names(DT)[j])
 }

DT
#  am gear carb
#1:  1 gear carb
#2:  1 gear carb
#3:  1 gear    1
#4:  0    3    1
#5:  0    3    2
```

---

If the dataset is a `data.frame`, then we can also do (not preferred with `data.table` though it works)

```
i1 <- DT == 4
DT[i1] <- rep(names(DT), each = nrow(DT))[i1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:
Use the mtcars as it is. Don't convert it into data.table. You can convert it later on.

```
DT <- mtcars[1:5, -c(1:8)]
DT

for (i in 1:length(colnames(DT))) {
  DT[,i] <- ifelse(DT[,i] == 4, colnames(DT)[i], NA)
}
DT2 <- data.table(DT)
DT2
```

This will give you the same result as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
> A=DT%>%`is.na<-`(DT==4)%>%rbind(names(DT),.)%>%
        fill(names(DT))%>%transmute_all(funs(`is.na<-`(.,grepl("\\d",.))))
> A[-1,]
    am gear carb
2 <NA> gear carb
3 <NA> gear carb
4 <NA> gear <NA>
5 <NA> <NA> <NA>
6 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```